# Java: Trying to create a file input program. But, user must input correct file name or it wont open

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Workshop5
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Prompting Scanner -> keyboard

  System.out.println("Hello, this program will be used to help determine miles per gallon used.");
  System.out.print("Please input file name here: ");
  keyboard.nextLine();
  Scanner fileIn = null ; // initializes fileIn to empty
  try
  {
  // Attempting to open your file.
     fileIn = new Scanner( new FileInputStream("MilesPerGallon.txt"));
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     System.out.println("File not found.");
     System.exit(0);
  }
  String name;
  double gasUsed;
  int milesDriven;
  name = fileIn.nextLine();
  gasUsed = fileIn.nextDouble();
  milesDriven = fileIn.nextInt();
  double milesPerGallon = (milesDriven/gasUsed);
  System.out.println(name + " drove " + milesDriven + " miles the other day, using a total of " + gasUsed + " gallons of gas.");
  fileIn.close();
  System.out.printf("Total number of Miles per Gallon: " + "%2.2f", milesPerGallon);
       }
   }
```

This is what i have. I have a file, names MilesPerGallon.txt. If i type in kashdkjashgkhjfgk it still opens the file MilesPerGallon.txt. Anyone know how I can create an if statement or something to make it to where the keyboard entered text for the file name MUST = MilesPerGallon.txt? Please help!

Comment: What do you think `new FileInputStream("MilesPerGallon.txt")` does? Why do you think so? Do you know how to compare strings?

Comment: No I don't, im in an intro to Java class. So the instructor didn't explain what this actually does. I'm going a little ambitious in trying to figure out how to do this. I love programming and I dont want to just make thing simple. Doesn't it ave to do with indicating the file path? Or pathway to the file, so the program can look in the same directory and locate the file named "X" ?

Comment: I also know this is formatted poorly, and probably illegal use of java grammar but its my rough draft and im VERY new. about 3 months into java. :/ Also i havent used inserts to explain my thoughts and attempts of some of the methods.

Comment: [Here's the class' Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html). Identify the corresponding constructor and read what it does.

Comment: What is the use of "file" variable ?

Comment: Then read the [official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html) on I/O.

Comment: @Rehman Ahh, I see its ambiguous! Thanks for the highlight. As I said, very new and i make silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Hello, this program will be used to help determine miles per gallon used.");
      System.out.print("Please input file name here: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Prompting Scanner -> keyboard
      String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
      Scanner fileIn = null ; // initializes fileIn to empty
      try
      {
      // Attempting to open your file.
         fileIn = new Scanner( new FileInputStream(fileName));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         System.out.println("File not found.. Please enter correct filename");
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(0);
      }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a larger explanation? Remeber, quite new, so most of the methods havent even been explained I was just told to use them. I get a syntax error when i replace it in my program. I use Jgrasp to form these programs.

Comment: You sir... are brilliance. I'm sorry for so many questions, but what exactly does that change? How does that make it to where you must enter the correct file name? If you are busy its okay i understand, but im very intrested and you seem to know what you're doing and i clearly dont

Comment: "fileName" will store the file name entered by you. Later I am creating a FileInputStream object with that file name. If JVM couldnt find that file name it will throw FileNotFoundException  which will be caught in the catch block and will print that message.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! Also, what is the point of fileIn = null; ? Why is this necessary

Comment: Not required. You can write :

 `Scanner fileIn = new Scanner( new FileInputStream(fileName));`

inside try block